# Counting characters in java

Tags: java, count, if-statement

I don't know how to insert a line of code that counts the numbers entered in a box that pops up.  Basically I can't enter more than 5 numbers.  So I think some sort of if statement needs to be inputed, which I don't know how to do.

Here is my code:

```
String number;


number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number");       


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The new result is" + number,"Results",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: a little shabby but how about something like this?

```
while(true)
{
    String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number");       

    if(number.length() >5 )
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,"Too Long! try again",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    else break;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant is that first a box pops up, then the user enters a 5 digit number.  If the number is more than 5 a box pops up that tells the user to enter just 5 numbers.

Comment: @Mike Edited! If you wnat the number value from the string, try using `int value = Integer.parseInt(number);`

Comment: That's working fine, but if the user enters a number that is longer than 5 how do I get the input box to pop up by itself? Right now the program just exits out and doesn't give the user a chance to re-enter the number.

Answer (score 0):

There are some complications to this, you don't check for non-numeric characters, for instance.

```
String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number");

number = number.trim(); // remove any spaces before and after
if (number.length() > 5 || hasNonNumeric(String)) {
   // show message
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Too long or non numeric characters in the string", 
   JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

boolean hasNonNumeric(String pSrc) {
    for (char c : pSrc.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is a bit safer.